# How to decrypt a hex stream using aes algorithm in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have decrypted a sample text using an [online tool](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) with a key.

Now I am trying to decrypt the obtained hex data using aes package in tcl.

Example :

---

Decrypted `hello world` using the above mentioned tool.

Key Used: `121301080D010518130E082007136412`

Obtained hex data : `edb191802afcec0deca6c9d725063cbc`

```
set hexData "edb191802afcec0deca6c9d725063cbc"
set key 121301080D010518130E082007136412
aes::aes -hex -mode ecb -dir decrypt -key $key $hexData 5bc428095e1cacdcef56f11c2bcdee58fe3d93098f641849831db0bce1e655fd <<<<
```

When I convert this hex to string, I am seeing the following output

```
[Ä( ^¬ÜïVñ+ÍîXþ=“   dIƒ°¼áæUý
```

Can anybody help me do it?

Comment: `aes::aes` is not an in-built command. What library are you using?

Comment: @Jerry I found a package named "aes" online. You can find the details of the package here "http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/aes.html#SECTid81dd148"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-hex` option isn't recommended; all it does is process the *output* of the `aes::aes` command so that it is rendered in hexadecimal. What it doesn't do is treat the *inputs* as hex.

You need the key and the encrypted data as binary values, whereas you've currently got them both as hexadecimal strings. It's not hard to convert though; `binary format H*` will do exactly what's required, and that appears to do what is wanted (cut-n-paste from an interactive session):

```
% aes::aes -dir decrypt -mode ecb -key [binary format H* $key] [binary format H* $hexData]
hello world
```

(CBC is the default mode.)

Mind you, I think you probably want to strip the trailing NULs from that result, and possibly reinterpret the bytes as UTF-8 (or whatever other encoding was used at the other end; remember, Tcl's strings are typically defined in terms of virtual Unicode characters, not in terms of byte sequences). Let's wrap this all up inside a procedure for reliability:

```
proc decryptAES {keyHex encryptedHex {encoding "utf-8"}} {
    set key [binary format H* $keyHex]
    set encrypted [binary format H* $encryptedHex]
    set decrypted [aes::aes -dir decrypt -mode ecb -key $key $encrypted]
    binary scan $decrypted A* bytes
    return [encoding convertfrom $encoding $bytes]
}
```

---

## Cheat sheet of standard Tcl commands used:

- `binary format H*` converts hex sequences to byte strings
- `binary scan … A*` reads the leading non-zero bytes from the byte string
- `encoding convertfrom` takes a byte string and interprets those bytes as text encoded using the given encoding (`encoding convertto` goes in the other direction).

Comment: Thank you...
But it is working only with encrypted data of 16 characters or less.
encrypted hex stream for "hello world hello world" is "8f3e789310ef604daaa257ed0e5345c85e56f289ce5d9a48efee466040ebf3db".
But when I decrypt this, the following is output copied from tcl shell
%decryptAES 121301080D010518130E082007136412 $hexData
hello world hellÃ Ã¼bÂƒMÂªÂ¢WÃ­SEÃˆ

Comment: @Surya OK, that was because the Tcllib aes package defaults to CBC mode (not documented!) and the code that encrypted used ECB mode. The difference is how following blocks are initialized; getting it wrong corrupts the stream after the first 16 bytes. I've revised my answer to use the right mode and it seems to work when I try it. Good comment!

Comment: Thanks a lot Donal, yes the default mode is ecb. I tried with more than 500 characters also, it is working fine. Your answer was very prompt. Thank you